# What's the best way to perform actions before a Model.save() using Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django-Rest-Framework(ViewSet approach) on my project interacting with a React app. So, I'm not using Django admin nor Django forms.

My project's structure is:

1. View
2. Serializer
3. Model

What I need to do is to perform actions before models method calls:

1. Insert the request.user on a Model field.
2. Start a printer process after a Model.save()
3. .....

I have read a lot about django-way to do on Django.docs and there, the things seems to be showed for a Django-Admin like project, which is not my case.

By other hand, by reading the Stack's answers about in other topics, the way to do seems to be like: "It will work, but, It's not the right way to do that".

1. According to Django's documentation, the  best way to perform that supposed to be by using a new file, called admin.py, where I would to register actions binding to a Model which could support save, delete, etc., but, it's not clear if this approach is to do that or only for provide a Django-Admin way to perform an action.

```py
# app/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

# app/admin.py

from app.models import Post, Comment
from django.contrib import admin

class CommentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('content',)

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields= ('content',)
    inlines = [CommentInline]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change): 
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change): 
        if formset.model == Comment:
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.user = request.user
                instance.save()
        else:
            formset.save()

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

According to the answers I have heard, the best way would use something like that on Models:

```py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
       return super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs['commit']=False
       obj = super(MyModelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       if self.request:
           obj.user = self.request.user
       obj.save()
       return obj
```

What I want to know is:
What's the best way to to perform that actions, on which files, what's the best structure.

Answer (score 0):

to insert a `request.user` on a Model field you can use the `perform_create()` method on your view class. for more information visit https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users which is exactly what u want!

I'm not sure what you mean by start a printer process, but you usually can override `save()` method on your model class for doing a process after saving a model instace.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-save-directly

Comment: Thank you. I meant printing data(by a printer) from that just saved Model.

Answer (score 0):

- The best way I found to insert the request.user on the model, as a "created_by" field, was by inserting a hidden field on the model serializer with a default data, just like these:

```py
my_field = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

The `CurrentUserDefault()` is a function wich returns the user request onto serializer.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#advanced-field-defaults

- For actions performing after/before a save/delete, what I chose to use Django Signals,wich works as a dispatcher of actions, a little like react's redux.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/

Thank you everybody for the helpful answers.